DHT11 value returns 0, but sensor is working
I'm working on a program that processes the data from a DHT11 sensor and returns the output to USART. I am using an STM32 F4 microcontroller for this project. It seems that I got something wrong in my code as there is an output in the USART, but I keep getting 0 values. Here is a snippet of the code that processes my DHT11 sensor and the main function:
void DHT11_ReadData(void) {
    uint8_t bits[5] = {0};

    // Request data from DHT11
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE1_0; // Set PA1 as output
    GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_1; // Pull the pin low
    delay_ms(20); // Wait for at least 18 ms
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE1; // Set PA1 as input

    // Wait for DHT11 to respond
    delay_us(40);

    // Check if DHT11 is sending data
    if (!(GPIOA->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID1)) { // Ensure the pin is pulled low by DHT11
        // Read data bits
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            // Wait for 40 µs (bit "1" or "0")
            delay_us(40);

            // Read the pin (bit value)
            if (GPIOA->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID1)
                bits[i / 8] |= (1 << (7 - (i % 8)));
        }

        // Checksum calculation
        uint8_t checksum = bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3];
        if (bits[4] == checksum) {
            // Store temperature and humidity values
            humidity = bits[0];
            temperature = bits[2];
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000); // Configure SysTick for 1ms interrupts
    DHT11_Init();
    USART2_Init();

    while (1) {
        // Read data from DHT11
        DHT11_ReadData();

        // Convert temperature and humidity to strings
        char tempStr[5];
        char humStr[5];
        sprintf(tempStr, "%d", temperature);
        sprintf(humStr, "%d", humidity);

        // Transmit data over USART
        USART2_SendString("Temperature: ");
        USART2_SendString(tempStr);
        USART2_SendString("°C, Humidity: ");
        USART2_SendString(humStr);
        USART2_SendString("%\r");
        USART2_SendString("\n");

        // Delay
        delay_ms(1000); // Delay for 2 seconds
    }
}

I hope you can help me with this. Thank you.

Hi, you haven't shown the code where you enable the clock from the RCC to the GPIO.  Also you haven't got any code on the "else" path of "Check if DHT11 is sending data".  What if it isn't ready yet?

Is your checksum calculation succeeding? If not, your variables won't get set, and I can imagine will always be zero.

Perhaps you have wrong timing: minimal tick is 1 ms SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000); but you use delay_us(40); to get 40 us delay. Any way this code is very sensitive to time and it will produce more problems later, when you'll become use IRQs.
